# how to post data from custom text box into facebook user timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

this code works if i pass data variable directly, but i want data from user input field,

$data = ["message" => "Testing post"];

$profile_request = $fb->post('/me/feed', $data);

the above code work, if i get from POST method its not working 
any suggestion will be appreciate,

```
index.php

    <?php
        require_once 'appconfig.php';
        $permissions = ['email','publish_actions'];
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/Api-Integeration/fbpost/logged.php', $permissions);
        //echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Post to Facebook!</a>';
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Post to user timeline</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <textarea rows="6" name="message" style="width:40%;" placeholder="Enter Post Data"></textarea>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="POST TO FACEBOOK" name="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>

logged.php

<?php 

require_once 'appconfig.php';

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: logged.php');
    }

    /*user messaegs*/

    $usermsg = $_POST['message'];

    $data = ["message" => $usermsg];

    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->post('/me/feed', $data);
        $user = $profile_request->getGraphUser();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header('Location: ./');
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else{
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "not set";
}

?>
```

Comment: The server-side login flow works by redirecting the user’s browser to Facebook, and then from there back to your app. At that point, there _is_ no POST data, because the browser makes GET requests to follow those redirects. You either need to pass the value along as a GET parameter through the login flow, so that it is still present when the user lands on your redirect URI, or store it into the session. Or, even better – you de-couple login and the form through which you are entering the message. Using POST to call the FB login URL does not make the most sense to begin with.